# Download multiple image at once from image gallery by creating a batch with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I was creating a image gallery with a facility for user to download multiple images by selecting them. Download result should be a zip file. I have a checkbox to select my images now I can't figure how do I download them.to select images we need to click select button and check the desired images and then download button should perform the action of download.
I want to perform the download using javascript
Please!! help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#image-album img').click(function () {
                var link =$(this).attr('src');
                var nextImage=$(this).next().attr('src'); 
                var prevImage=$(this).prev().attr('src');
                $('#imagepreview').attr('src',link);
                $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
                var nextImage=$(this).next().attr('src');
            });
        });
        $( "#selectbtn" ).click(function() {
            var state = $(".custom-checkbox").css("visibility");
            if(state==='visible'){
                state='hidden';
            }
            else{
                state='visible';
            }
            $(".custom-checkbox").css('visibility',state);  
        });
```

```css
#image-album img{
                max-height: 200px;
                max-width: 200px;
            }   
            .custom-checkbox{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-11 py-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-2" id="downloadbtn">Download</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="selectbtn">Select</button>
    </div><br>
    <span id="image-album">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271632/pexels-photo-271632.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271632/pexels-photo-271632.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276696/pexels-photo-276696.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276696/pexels-photo-276696.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271805/pexels-photo-271805.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271805/pexels-photo-271805.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271724/pexels-photo-271724.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271724/pexels-photo-271724.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276599/pexels-photo-276599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276599/pexels-photo-276599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276599/pexels-photo-276599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276599/pexels-photo-276599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276599/pexels-photo-276599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/276599/pexels-photo-276599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    </span>     

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To Download images as zip file you need to do code on server side. after selecting images you have to call server side code(like web service) and pass the selected images to this method and server will make a zip file and send back to user

Comment: Is there a way to download them with javascript?

Comment: You can try https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a fiddle for you
[See working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/pq1hetr2/1/)

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.0.2/jszip-utils.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-11 py-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-2" id="downloadbtn">Download</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="selectbtn">Select</button>
    </div><br>
    <span id="image-album">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://s31.postimg.cc/t6p5hyfsb/pexels-photo-271632.jpg">
        <img src="https://s31.postimg.cc/t6p5hyfsb/pexels-photo-271632.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">

        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://s31.postimg.cc/eni0gq24r/pexels-photo-276696.jpg">
        <img src="https://s31.postimg.cc/eni0gq24r/pexels-photo-276696.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">

         <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://s31.postimg.cc/a2vu1hd6z/pexels-photo-271724.jpg">
        <img src="https://s31.postimg.cc/a2vu1hd6z/pexels-photo-271724.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">

         <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="https://s31.postimg.cc/kcy90qq7v/pexels-photo-276599.jpg">
        <img src="https://s31.postimg.cc/kcy90qq7v/pexels-photo-276599.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">    

    </span>     

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var Promise = window.Promise;
if (!Promise) {
    Promise = JSZip.external.Promise;
}
function urlToPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};
/**
 * Reset the message.
 */
function resetMessage () {
    $("#result")
    .removeClass()
    .text("");
}
/**
 * show a successful message.
 * @param {String} text the text to show.
 */
function showMessage(text) {
    resetMessage();
    $("#result")
    .addClass("alert alert-success")
    .text(text);
}
/**
 * show an error message.
 * @param {String} text the text to show.
 */
function showError(text) {
    resetMessage();
    $("#result")
    .addClass("alert alert-danger")
    .text(text);
}
/**
 * Update the progress bar.
 * @param {Integer} percent the current percent
 */
function updatePercent(percent) {
    $("#progress_bar").removeClass("hide")
    .find(".progress-bar")
    .attr("aria-valuenow", percent)
    .css({
        width : percent + "%"
    });
}

if(!JSZip.support.blob) {
    showError("This demo works only with a recent browser !");
    return;
}
$(document).ready(function () {


            $('#image-album img').click(function () {
                var link =$(this).attr('src');
                var nextImage=$(this).next().attr('src'); 
                var prevImage=$(this).prev().attr('src');
                $('#imagepreview').attr('src',link);
                $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
                var nextImage=$(this).next().attr('src');
            });
            $( "#selectbtn" ).click(function() {
            var state = $(".custom-checkbox").css("visibility");
            if(state==='visible'){
                state='hidden';
            }
            else{
                state='visible';
            }
            $(".custom-checkbox").css('visibility',state);  
        });
        $( "#downloadbtn" ).click(function() {
            var zip = new JSZip();
            $('#image-album').find(":checked").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $this.val();
        var filename = url.replace(/.*\//g, "");
        zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});
       });
       // when everything has been downloaded, we can trigger the dl
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}, function updateCallback(metadata) {
        var msg = "progression : " + metadata.percent.toFixed(2) + " %";
        if(metadata.currentFile) {
            msg += ", current file = " + metadata.currentFile;
        }


    })
    .then(function callback(blob) {

        // see FileSaver.js
        saveAs(blob, "example.zip");


    }, function (e) {
        showError(e);
    });

        });
        });
```